# Prevent sending a specific key if I'm pressing other 2 or more keys

Tags: script, autohotkey

I have this mouse with additional forward and back buttons at the side and here's an AHK script that I use with it, It's main purpose is:

1. If middle mouse button is scrolled up while holding down XButton2 (forward button) and Right Button (Right Click) It sends <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>.
2. If middle mouse button is scrolled up while holding down mouse XButton2, It increases system volume by 2%

The problem is it also triggers the default action of mouse XButton2 (Forward) at the same time so I wanted to prevent it from sending "Forward" when I held the keys stated above.

```
~XButton2 & WheelUp::
GetKeyState, RButtonState, RButton,     ;Gets the mouses Rbutton state
If RButtonState = D                     ;Checks if Rbutton is pressed down

if (x_1 > 1919) ;if mouse cursor's X(Horizontal) position is greater than 1919px then:
Send !6         ;Sends ALT+6
else Send !4    ;Sends ALT+4

SetNumlockState, On


If RButtonState = U  ;Checks if Rbutton is NOT pressed down
SoundSet, + 2        ;if Rbutton is not pressed down scrolling up while holding XButton2 increases volume
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tilde prefix (~)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) prevents AHK from blocking the XButton2 key-down/up events. It allows the key event to pass through.

If you remove ~, XButton2 [loses its original function](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo). To avoid this, make the key to send itself:

```
XButton2 & WheelUp::
; do something
return  

XButton2::Send {XButton2}
```